# How to delete video file in Android 10+ devices without MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in a video player adapter?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm building a video player in my Android app and need to be able to delete video files after they have been played. However, I don't want to require the **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission as this may put off some users. Is there any way to delete video files without this permission in Android 10+ devices?

Additionally, I'm using a RecyclerView with a video player adapter to display the videos, so any solution would need to work within this context. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not for Android 10 devices.

Comment: please chechk what i told , android 10+ devices means android 10 above devices

Comment: 10+ means 10 and above.

Comment: yes, how to delete file

Comment: You should rewrite your post as as said before: MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not for Android 10 and you suggest it does.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can delete files without permission using root access and linux commands.

```
            try {
                Process p;
                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
                os.writeBytes("rm -f /sdcard/Download/file.mp4\n");

                // Close the terminal
                os.writeBytes("exit\n");
                os.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
```

But seriously, security is a good thing. Regarding to put off some users, the android website has an article on how to proceed when requesting permissions.
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: if i request this permissionMANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE than google playstore reject my app but without this permisssion, one way to delete this file but when i am using this function in adapter that not work